# Test $http in Angular service with Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

I'm having a hard time testing $http within an Angular service. The service code works in my module but I can't seem to test it successfully. Do I need to change the way my service is structured? $httpBackend is not being hit in either case outlined below.

My service:

```
angular.module('myApp')

.service('backendApi', [
  "$http"
  function(
    $http
  ){
    this.getThis = function(getPath) {
      return $http({method: 'GET', url: getPath});
    };
  }
]);
```

My test:

```
describe("backend API", function () {
  var backendApi;

  beforeEach(module('myApp'));

  beforeEach(inject(function (_backendApi_, $httpBackend) {
    backendApi = _backendApi_;

    $httpBackend.when('GET', 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1').respond({
      'mocked': 'data'
    });
  }));


  it('gets data from API', function () {

    expect(
      backendApi.getThis('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
    ).toEqual({ 'mocked': 'data' });

    backendApi.getThis('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1').then(function(data) {
       expect(data).toEqual('Not getting here..');
    });

  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being an easy fix. I needed to flush the backend to apply the changes.

```
backendApi.getThis('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1').then(function(response.data) {
   expect(response.data).toEqual({ 'mocked': 'data' });
});

httpBackend.flush();
```